# Failing validations in join model when using has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My full code can be seen at https://github.com/andyw8/simpleform_examples

I have a join model `ProductCategory` with the following validations:

```
validates :product, presence: true
validates :category, presence: true
```

My `Product` model has the following associations:

```
has_many :product_categories
has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
```

When I try to create a new product with a category, the call to `@product.save!` in the controller fails with:

```
Validation failed: Product categories is invalid
```

When I remove the validations, everything works and the join models are saved correctly.

I'm using `strong_parameters` but I don't *think* that should be related to this issue.

Comment: did you removed this `validates_associated` from `ProductCategory` model and tried to save @product.save! because which is no need.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a "racing condition" in the callback chain.

When you create a product it doesn't have any id before it is saved, therefore there is no `product` in the scope of `ProductCategory`.

```
Product.new(name: "modern times", category_ids:[1, 2]) #=> #<Product id: nil >
```

At that stage of validation (before saving), `ProductCatgory` cannot assign any id to it's foreign key `product_id`.

That's the reason you have association validations : so that the validation happens in the scope of the whole transaction

UPDATE: As said in the comment you still can't ensure presence of a product/category. There's many ways around depending on why you want do this (e.g direct access to ProductCategory through some form)

- You can create a flag to have `validates :product, presence: true, if: :direct_access?`
- or if you can only update them: `validates :product, presence: true, on: "update"`
- create your product first (in the products_controller) and add the categories after

... But indeed these are all compromises or workarounds from the simple `@product.create(params)`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But when I specify validates_associated on :product and :category, this doesn't prevent a ProductCategory being created without those associations.

Comment: I've updated the post to address your comment. Oh you can also override category_ids=(array) to save the product prior to the association... But I don't see anything else than having to write more code...

Answer (score 10):

Specifying `inverse_of` on your joining models has been documented to fix this issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-6330795
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7661#issuecomment-8614206

**Simplified Example:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_categories, :inverse_of => :product
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_categories, inverse_of: :category
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates :product, presence: true
  validates :category, presence: true
end

Product.new(:categories => [Category.new]).valid? # complains that the ProductCategory is invalid without inverse_of specified
```

Adapted from: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8269#issuecomment-12032536

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just need to define your relationships better.  I still might have missed some, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :color_scheme, presence: true

  belongs_to :color_scheme

  has_many :product_categories, inverse_of: :product
  has_many :categories, through: :product_categories
end


class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates_associated :product
  validates_associated :category

  # TODO work out why this causes ProductsController#create to fail
  # validates :product, presence: true
  # validates :category, presence: true
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_categories, inverse_of: :category
  has_many :products, through: :product_categories
end
```