# Rails: Has_many through, nested checkboxes, and validating presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, nested-attributes

I'm sure this is a common problem, but it has me stumped.

I have a has_many :through table on a 'Step' model:

```
has_many :questions, :through => :question_step
```

That question_step model has presence validators on the question_id and step_id fields:

```
validates_presence_of :question_id, :step_id
```

And there are checkboxes that determine which questions belong to which step

```
td= check_box_tag "step[question_ids][]", question.id, @step.question_ids.include?(question.id)
```

Now, this works just fine, except when I want to add questions to a *new* step. Because step_id is blank, the question_step model fails validation. It works fine if I remove the validate_presence_of :step_id argument in the question_step model, but I actually *do* want to ensure that the step_id is there.

I'm sure this is a common problem. ...Any thoughts?

Comment: Look into [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132) and its reject_if param. Also check out [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: You may need to add inverse_of to your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than validating the step and question IDs are present, you could check if there is a question and step object:

```
validates_presence_of :question, :step
```

If that doesn't work you should consider removing the application level validations and adding database constraints instead, you just need to add a not null constraint to the columns in a migration:

```
def up
  change_column question_steps, :question_id, :integer, :null => false
  change_column question_steps, :step_id,     :integer, :null => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140994/failing-validations-in-join-model-when-using-has-many-through) there is a race condition occurring.

In my controller's create action I decided to create my main model without the associations first using params which exclude the association params. And then update the model with the association params.

So in your case it might be

```
def create
  @step = Step.create(create_params)
  @step.update_attributes(association_params) unless @step.errors.any?
  respond_to do |format|
    if @step.errors.empty?
      format.html #etc..
    else
      format.html#...etc..
    end
  end
end

private
def create_params
  perm_params = step_params
  perm_params.delete :question_ids
  perm_params
end
def association_params
  params.require(:step).permit(question_ids: [])
end
def step_params
  params.require(:step).permit(:name, :other_attributes, question_ids: [])
end
```

This way you do not have to move the validations to your db. You would still use the normal step_params in your update method.

The params methods could probably be DRYed up a bit and I am wondering why I need to go to all this fuss for something which worked simply in rails 3, but it works now for me.